# Searching through values in dynamic array (vba)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Users select desired options through use of a checkbox.  The caption values of each check box are stored in a dynamic array then displayed in message box confirming the selections.

I now need to loop through a range of cells, at every row determining if cell (x,4) is equal to any value in the array, but I don't know how to loop like that.  See code below where the array is populated.

Thank you in advance!

```
Sub ProcessStrats_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim cnt As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cResp As Integer
Dim stArray() As Variant

    cnt = 0                                             'Initialize counter outside of loop
    For Each ctl In StratFill.Controls                  'look at every control in StratForm box
        If Left(ctl.Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then          'if the control is named 'checkbox' then
            If ctl.Value = True Then                    'if the control is marked as 'true' i.e. checked, then
                ReDim Preserve stArray(0 To cnt)        'Reset the array dimension on each iteration of loop
                stArray(cnt) = ctl.Caption              'Add value in value of checkbox caption to Array
                cnt = cnt + 1                           'Advance the counter to next array item
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Unload StratFill                                    'unload and close stratfill form


    msg = "The following strategies will be priced:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    For i = LBound(stArray) To UBound(stArray)          'loops through all values of array
           msg = msg & stArray(i) & vbCR                'strings together displayed txt
    Next i

        If MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Confirm Strategies") = vbYes Then
                                                                    'if yes is clicked
            Call RunPricing                                         '"RunPricing" will run
        Else                                                        'if no is clicked
            StratFill.Show                                          'then the strategy selector box will display again
        End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(stArray)                        'loops through all values of array

    Range("$D2:" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Select

    Selection.Find(What:=stArray(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(0, 2).Select

    msg = msg & stArray(i) & ActiveCell.Value & vbCR                'strings together displayed txt
Next i
```

Comment: Rather than displaying it in a message, is there a way to mark initiate an If Then process for each one that is found to match a value in the array?

Comment: @emsbish in your original question you have: `msg = msg & stArray(i) & vbCR                'strings together displayed txt`  You can run your process on the value found by ref. ActiveCell.Value or .Range.  Just replace the `msg = msg` statment.